# Explicitly set the geckodriver version with webdriver-manager for Protractor tests

Tags: selenium, firefox, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to run my protractor tests in Chrome and Firefox simultaneously, and have explicitly told it to run with v2.30 of the chromedriver, yet when trying to use older versions of geckodriver (running `webdriver-manager update --versions.firefox=0.17.0`, `webdriver-manager update --versions.gecko=0.17.0`, and `webdriver-manager update --versions.geckodriver=0.17.0`), it still installs the latest version (0.18.0 at the time of writing).

Is there a way to install a specific version of the driver for Firefox?  If yes, what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using wrong parameter. Below works for me

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.gecko=v0.17.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be set from webdriver-manager?  You can do it in the config yourself.  From [Protractor's Reference Config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L78):

> /*** geckoDriver location is used to help find the gecko binary. This will be passed to the Selenium jar as the system property webdriver.gecko.driver. If the value is not set when launching locally, it will use the default values downloaded from webdriver-manager.
>     `geckoDriver?: string;`

So download the whatever version you need manually and add the path to the `geckoDriver` property with the path as that value in your config.

Geckodriver releases can be found on their [GitHub Page](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)